# Erase the HTML website and replace it with a WordPress website -301 Redirection

Tags: redirect, migration, seo

We are going to erase the HTML website and replace it with a WordPress website (New redesigned site).
We already have 301 redirection( http to https) in .htaccess file. Is this 301 redirection is enough to maintain the SERP ranking/pass the link juice? 
Or 
Are we need to add extra page level 301 redirection for all the pages/important pages to its corresponding Wordpress pages.

Eg :   /about.html to /about

Comment: If you want to use same URL in the wordpress you can also use the `.html` extension in permalink setting. For more info check this: http://wpflux.com/14830-add-html-extension-wordpress-permalink-urls/

Comment: Hi Baikare Sandeep, Thanks for the reply. We are not going to use  .html, We have setup new customized urls.